# Using android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"/> And It is Messing Up My Landscape Layout on Orientation change

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout, android-configchanges

When I put in

```
activity android:name=".MainActivity" 
android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"
```

and do it for each one of my activities, the layout when I flip the orientation in the emulator doesn't match how I made it in design mode.

Before, when I didn't have the configChanges it would work just perfectly, except if I was playing audio it would keep playing and I wouldn't have a way to pause the audio that was playing when I first started it.

How do I keep the layout the same as where I designed it in my landscape activity when I run the emulator and at the same time be able to use configChanges so that the state of the object remains the same?

This is what my code looks like in my `Manifest.xml` file for the configChanges:

```
<activity android:name=".MainActivity" 
android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"/>
    <activity android:name=".Listen" 
android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"/>
    <activity android:name=".See" 
android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"/>
    <activity android:name=".Study" 
android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize" />
```

Comment: you should save your state in `onSaveInstanceState` to save anything you need in a bundle then use `onRestoreInstanceState` to get everything https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onSaveInstanceState(android.os.Bundle)

Answer (score 1):

Despite what the internet tells you, you should *never** use the `android:configChanges` attribute to suppress the normal lifecycle of Android activities. Instead, you should work within the system as it normally functions.

From Google's own [documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element#config):

> **Note:** Using this attribute should be avoided and used only as a last resort. Please read [Handling Runtime Changes](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/runtime-changes) for more information about how to properly handle a restart due to a configuration change.

---

In your case, this means solving the other problem you mentioned:

> if I was playing audio it would keep playing and I wouldn't have a way to pause the audio that was playing when I first started it

I'd recommend opening a new question with details about how you start/stop the audio that's playing and with information on exactly what "the problem" is. I *suspect* that the right way to handle this will be to move the audio handling into a [retained fragment](https://www.androiddesignpatterns.com/2013/04/retaining-objects-across-config-changes.html), but I can't do more than guess for now.

Comment: Thank you. I'm quite new to this so any help is greatly appreciated. I am trying to keep the audio in the same state when I rotate it and to have the layout match my landscape layout that I created. I don't know how to do this, and I am not sure how to do a retained fragment but maybe I'll look more into it. This is for a project and I don't have that much more time to do it, so I may have to just do it without saving the state. Thank you anyway.